# Python - Datetime Problem printing '%p' with locale

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

I have a simple script that fetches a UTC datetime from an API and then I try to parse it to

```
"%I:%M:%S %p . %d de %B del %Y"
```

I get the correct format without a locale set (12:35:01 PM. 15 de November del 2023).
But when I try to get the Spanish month, the %p suddenly disappears.

```
def get_time():
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'es_ES.utf8')
    
    sharepoint_api = api.SharePointAPI()
    last_time_ran = sharepoint_api.get_last_executed_time()
    
    #Change UTC to local timezone
    utc_format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"
    utc_time = datetime.strptime(last_time_ran, utc_format)
    utc_time = utc_time.replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
    
    local_tz = pytz.timezone("America/Monterrey")
    local_time = utc_time.astimezone(local_tz)
    
    # Parse to desired format
    output_format = "%I:%M:%S %p . %d de %B del %Y"
    formatted_date = local_time.strftime(output_format)
    
    return formatted_date
```

This prints:

```
12:35:01 . 15 de Noviembre del 2023
```

Different workarounds say I should use a dictionary to change the months, or parse the date before the locale is set to get the PM/AM and then add it after the locale.

Isn't there an easier way? Is this a datetime library bug?

Comment: Do they use AM/PM in Spain? Maybe they always use 24-hour time.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they do. Either way, "%H" already exists for 24-hour time.

Anyways, thanks. Setting the locale to es-MX worked.

Comment: I get an error when I try to do `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'es_ES.utf8')`: locale.Error: unsupported locale setting

Comment: Had to change `utf8` to `utf-8`

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. `datetime.datetime.now().strftime(output_format)` returns `'05:28:30 PM . 15 de noviembre del 2023'`

Comment: This sounds like a problem with your locale database, not the script.

Comment: @Barmar Weird. How can the locale database be edited?

Comment: I have no idea, that's operating system stuff.